# swipe to delete option breaking the tableviewcell functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

So I have been creating a  tableviewcontroller that handles my tableview and its tableviewcells..
Here's the code––

ItemsViewController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

    -(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;

    @end
```

ItemsViewController.m

```
    @implementation ItemsViewController

   -(id) init{
      self= [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
         if (self) {
            UINavigationItem *n= [self navigationItem];
              [n setTitle:@"Homepwner"];


             for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
               [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
             }

        }
        return self;
     }
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
     {
           return [self init];

      }
   - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
         NSLog(@"ItemsView loaded");
         [super viewDidLoad];

           UIBarButtonItem *bbi= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];//Target-Action pair..
         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= bbi;
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
  }
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       NSLog(@"ItemsView appearing");
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       [[self tableView] reloadData];
   }

   -(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender{
       BNRItem *newItem= [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
       NSLog(@"%d",[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count]);
       int newRow = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] indexOfObject:newItem];
       NSIndexPath *ip= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0];
       [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

   //Row Selection
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
         if(indexPath.row<[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems].count){
            NSLog(@"Row# %d selected",indexPath.row);
            DetailViewController *detailViewController= [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
             NSArray *items= [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];

            BNRItem *item= [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           detailViewController.item=item;//BNRItem at the selected indexPath.

            //Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
           [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
       }
       else{
          return;
     }
   }

   #pragma mark - Table view data source

     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       {
            NSLog(@"Test1");
           return 1;
        }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
       {
          //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
            // Return the number of rows in the section.
             NSLog(@"Current section- %d",section);

          return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count]+1 ;//no. of rows (5)+'No more items' row
        }

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
         {
             NSLog(@"hello");
           //    NSLog(@"%@",headerView);
           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

          // Configure the cell...
           if (!cell) {
              cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
           }
            if (indexPath.row<[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems].count) {
              [[cell textLabel] setText:[[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAt  Index:indexPath.row] description]];
           }
           else if (indexPath.row== [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems].count)
            {
                [[cell textLabel] setText:@"No more items"];
            }
            return cell;
         }


           // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
     - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
           // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
             if (self.editing) {
                 NSLog(@"Editing is on");
                 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
                 if (indexPath.row==[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems].count) {
                     [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].hidden=YES;
                     return NO;// Do not make 'No more items' editable.
                }
       }
       else{//When the user is out of editing mode
           NSLog(@"editing done");
           [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].hidden=NO;
           self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=YES;
       }

        return YES;
    }



      // Override to support editing the table view.
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
           if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
              NSLog(@"Deletion is on");
            // Delete the row from the data source
              NSArray *items= [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
              BNRItem *p= [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
              [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] removeItem:p];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       }
          else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
       }
    }



        // Override to support rearranging the table view.
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
        {
          [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row toIndex:toIndexPath.row];
        }

     -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedIndexPath{
     if (proposedIndexPath.row==[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems].count) {// 'No more items' row
         return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:proposedIndexPath.row-1 inSection:0];
      }
         return proposedIndexPath;
    }
  @end
```

When the editing mode is on i.e when i tap Edit button on the NavBar the Add button grays out and the 'No more items' rows becomes hidden. After exiting Edit mode (by tapping 'Done' button) the Add button becomes selectable and the 'No more items' row unhides.. This is all fine when i perform editing by first entering the Edit mode and then exiting the Edit mode. But when instead of using the above way, i use **swipe to delete** feature, the view doesn't realize the above functionality (i.e. **Ungraying/Re-enabling** the **Add** button once i'm done doing a deletion using the **swipe to delete** thing. When i swipe across a cell **(so as to bring up the delete button on the right side of the cell and graying out the Add button in the process)** and choose not to press the 'Delete' button by just retapping on the cell **(so that the Delete button goes away)** *the Add button does not update itself so as to get enabled..* What to do about. Pls carefully examine my code first and give recommendations accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

use this tableView Delegate mathod

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
 return NO;
 }
```

Please Utilize the  [Apple Library- UItableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: i can see myself using the 3rd method that u suggested. It is a handy feature and wouldn't make the 'No more Items' row become out of place while all the other data related cell are in editing mode.. Nonetheless it isn't a solution to my problem. The problem is swipe to delete feature. When i swipe across a cell the Add button grays and delete button comes up. Uptill here, its all fine. What i want is the moment i press the delete button, the Add button should become re-enabled. The first method u mentioned has already implemented in my code.. Pls examine my code carefully.

Comment: When i do the swipe action on a cell and the delete button appears, i choose to dismiss it by retapping the cell so the button goes away and the cell exits the edit mode. But the Add button is not getting re-enabled. However when i press the Done button while the cell is in edit mode then it works properly in that the Add button is re-enabled. I have already included the code for when to gray out Add button and when to re-enable it in the code on top.. Its working fine except for when i use 'swipe to delete' feature. Help me fix that